# compare numbers with tolerance

Tags: php

Probably a dumb question but is there a more clever way of checking that 
an image 1360x455 is within the allowed tolerance of say +-10 of two other numbers I have defined?  :

```
<?php
$w = 1360;
$h = 455;

$cw = 1360;
$ch = 460;

$tol = 10; //px
if ((int) $w >= (int) ($cw-$tol) && (int) $w <= (int) ($cw+$tol) &&
    (int) $h >= (int) ($ch-$tol) && (int) $h <= (int) ($ch+$tol)) {

    echo "you are within the tolerance {$cw}x{$ch}px by +-{$tol} px.";
};
```

So I basically just want to make sure the user doesn't go outside of these bounds when uploading. The above code works, just wondering if I could be more clever about it. The method already knows these values as they are passed in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A more concise method would be to subtract the input value against the reference and ensure the absolute value ([`abs()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.abs.php)) of the result is less than or equal to your tolerance.

The difference between the reference value an input value must be within 10, and subtracting them will produce a positive or negative integer. Using `abs()` strips its sign, so it's a simple `<=` comparison with the tolerance value.

```
$w = 1360;
$h = 455;

$cw = 1360;
$ch = 460;

$tol = 10; //px

if (abs($cw - $w) <= $tol && abs($ch - $h) <= $tol) {
  echo "you are within the tolerance {$cw}x{$ch}px by +-{$tol} px.";
}
```

The casting with `(int)` is generally unnecessary here. But if your function may be receiving string values, I would suggest casting the variables to ints before the calculation just so to reduce clutter.

Comment: @MikeQ Glad to help.